# React Native Flexwrap breaks ScrollView wont scroll

Tags: react-native, flexbox, scrollview

I am trying to get my items to wrap horizontally, and they do. It's only when I add flexWrap: "wrap" does the scrollview decide not to scroll at all.

```
<ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap', alignItems: 'flex- 
     start',}}>  
    <FrameComponent />
    <FrameComponent />
    <FrameComponent />
    <FrameComponent />
    <FrameComponent />
    ...
</ScrollView>
```

With the FrameComponent rendering

```
<View>
    <Text>
        ...
    </Text>
<View>
```

And the styles for the frame component being some simple flex and margin stuff.

This scrolls with all the other settings, but as soon as I add flexWrap, it goes bezerk.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Ok so i extended the number of components being drawn onto the screen and it does scroll, it just didn't reach its limit to start scrolling. It seems to be extending the height of the scrollpane instead of fitting it into it's natural place. Any thoughts to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Pass horizontal = {true} prop to your ScrollView and remove flex wrap and  flexDirection styles.

```
<ScrollView horizontal = {true}>
...
</ScrollView>
```

[Horizontal ScrollView in React Native](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#horizontal)